# How to create a dataclass with a list parameter that has default value and can be assigned with constructor?

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

Is there a **simple** way to create a data class with a list property `items` that has default values `[1, 2, 3]` such that I can assign it other values `[4, 5, 6]` with the **constructor** `MyStruct(items=[4, 5, 6])`?

If I run the following code I get error:

> TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'items'

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class MyStruct:
    item: str = "Hello"
    items = [1, 2, 3]  # I need a list with default values

struct = MyStruct(item="Bye")  # No problem here
struct = MyStruct(items=[4, 5, 6])  # Error "unexpected keyword argument"
```

I tried assigning `list` type to `items`, and also using `field` function, but had no luck. I want a **simple** solution, without writing a lot of code, like a custom `__init__` method.

Comment: `items: list = field(default_factory=lambda : [1,2,3])`?

Comment: Yes, it does help, thanks.